# How to turn around strings in dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a `name`, something like **Robin the Bruyne** or **Victor from the Loo**
These names are in a `dataframe` in my session. I need to change these names into:

<*lastname, firstname middlename(s)*>,

so they are turn arouned. But I don't know how to do this.

I know I can use things like `separate()` or `map()` with `PURR` (of `tidyverse`).

Data:

```
  ~nr,            ~name,        ~prodno,
  2019001,       "Piet de Boer", "lux_zwez",
  2019002,       "Elly Hamstra",  "zuv_vla",
  2019003, "Sue Ellen Schilder",  "zuv_vla",
  2019004,      "Truus Janssen", "zuv_vmlk",
  2019005,  "Evelijne de Vries", "lux_zwez",
  2019006,     "Berend Boersma", "lux_gras",
  2019007,   "Marius van Asten",  "zuv_vla",
  2019008,     "Corneel Jansen", "lux_gras",
  2019009,     "Joke Timmerman",  "zuv_vla",
  2019010, "Jan Willem de Jong", "lux_zwez",
  2019011,   "Frederik Janssen", "zuv_vmlk",
  2019012,   "Antonia de Jongh", "zuv_vmlk",
  2019013,   "Lena van der Loo",  "zuv_qrk",
  2019014,   "Johanna Haanstra", "lux_gras"
```

Comment: would the `lastname` and `firstname` consist of only one word?

Comment: Is the format always firstname, middlename, lastname? What would `Victor from the Loo` become? `The Loo from Victor`?

Comment: Probably you'd need to use the fact that first and last name seem to start with an upper case letter.

Comment: @Sotos Yes it is. Then it will be Loo, Victor from the

Comment: @RonakShah No first name can be something like Peter-Jan

Comment: Please post an example of your dataframe, use `dput(head(data))` for example.

Answer (score 4):

We can try using `sub` here:

```
names <- c("Robin the Bruyne", "Victor from the Loo")
output <- sub("^(.*) ([A-Z][a-z]+)$", "\\2, \\1", names)
output

[1] "Bruyne, Robin the"    "Loo, Victor from the"
```

This approach uses the following pattern:

```
^(.*)          capture everything from the start until the last space
([A-Z][a-z]+)$ capture the last name, which starts with a capital
```

Then, we replace with the last name and first/middle names swapped, separated by a comma.

Comment: Thanks but I need to adress that I want to `change` the `names` in the dataframe.  Later on I will have a dataframe with more columns than only one. How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  If you don't just want a single column replacement, then how many columns do you want, and what do you expect in each column?

Comment: I will have a dataframe with ordernumbers, `names`, and dates. But with your solution now, it isn't clear which column need to be changed

Comment: It isn't clear to me how my answer should change.  If you can articulate that, I'm happy to edit my answer.

Comment: It does not work now, the names are staying the same because in this code it is not clear which `column` is led to this code. What if your `names` example has also a date example in it?

Comment: What if de dataframe has not only one column (names) but more? How can you adress that the column names need to get swapped? In your example you just have only one 'column' with two names but I have also dates and ordernumbers. With your code it is not clear then which column needs to get swapped.

Comment: And your question is equally unclear, because you never gave us any sample data which covers these edge cases.

Comment: Added my data now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this should work.

```r
dat = tibble::tribble(
  ~nr,            ~name,        ~prodno,
  2019001,       "Piet de Boer", "lux_zwez",
  2019002,       "Elly Hamstra",  "zuv_vla",
  2019003, "Sue Ellen Schilder",  "zuv_vla",
  2019004,      "Truus Janssen", "zuv_vmlk",
  2019005,  "Evelijne de Vries", "lux_zwez",
  2019006,     "Berend Boersma", "lux_gras",
  2019007,   "Marius van Asten",  "zuv_vla",
  2019008,     "Corneel Jansen", "lux_gras",
  2019009,     "Joke Timmerman",  "zuv_vla",
  2019010, "Jan Willem de Jong", "lux_zwez",
  2019011,   "Frederik Janssen", "zuv_vmlk",
  2019012,   "Antonia de Jongh", "zuv_vmlk",
  2019013,   "Lena van der Loo",  "zuv_qrk",
  2019014,   "Johanna Haanstra", "lux_gras"
)

library(magrittr)
dat %>% dplyr::mutate(
  lastname = stringr::str_extract(name,"(?<=[:blank:])[:alnum:]+$"),
  firstname = stringr::str_extract(name,".*(?=[:blank:])"),
  name = paste(lastname,firstname,sep = ", ")
) %>% dplyr::select(-firstname,-lastname)
#> # A tibble: 14 x 3
#>         nr name                prodno  
#>      <dbl> <chr>               <chr>   
#>  1 2019001 Boer, Piet de       lux_zwez
#>  2 2019002 Hamstra, Elly       zuv_vla 
#>  3 2019003 Schilder, Sue Ellen zuv_vla 
#>  4 2019004 Janssen, Truus      zuv_vmlk
#>  5 2019005 Vries, Evelijne de  lux_zwez
#>  6 2019006 Boersma, Berend     lux_gras
#>  7 2019007 Asten, Marius van   zuv_vla 
#>  8 2019008 Jansen, Corneel     lux_gras
#>  9 2019009 Timmerman, Joke     zuv_vla 
#> 10 2019010 Jong, Jan Willem de lux_zwez
#> 11 2019011 Janssen, Frederik   zuv_vmlk
#> 12 2019012 Jongh, Antonia de   zuv_vmlk
#> 13 2019013 Loo, Lena van der   zuv_qrk 
#> 14 2019014 Haanstra, Johanna   lux_gras
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>